# EFCore queries throttled at 1000 when repeatedly querying in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I noticed that my ASP.NET app, which imports CSVs and turns them into DB entities, was dramatically slowing down a certain way through the import process.

Version info: EFCore 2.2.3, .NET Core 2.0

It seemed to be getting stuck when querying the database for the CSV row, to check if the entity already exists. What's weird is that it's totally fine up to that point, and it stops at *almost* exactly 1000 queries, every single time. After this point there's a smattering of logs indicating threads are exiting, then it processes another handful, freezes again, rinse and repeat.

I've been investigating various theories, eventually I boiled it down to this example (it actually runs off in its own thread, but to simplify the example I moved it to a controller method):

### Startup.cs

```cs
...
// We use an extended DbContext that defines the various DbSets as usual
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString));
...
```

### SomeController.cs

```cs
private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

public SomeController(DatabaseContext context) 
{
    _context = context;
}

[Route("/SomeController/TestQueries")]
public async Task<JsonResult> TestQueries()
{
    await TestRepeatedQueries();
    return null;
}

private async Task TestRepeatedQueries()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Fetching for iteration {i}");
        _ = await _context.SomeTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // Nothing fancy
        // It doesn't appear that table complexity is a factor
        // The problem occurs even with a simple table with an ID and a few integers
    }
}
```

On hitting the controller method, the logs show that it fires away merrily, querying the DB for around 1000 iterations, but then just stops. It seems that some random worker threads are exited, and after maybe 5 seconds or so, it blasts through another ~10 iterations, so on and so forth.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, it almost seems like there's some query limit that's being hit, and it's taking some time for the resources to be freed up before being able to resume?

For any clarifications please ask!

## Update

For some unknown reason, it's just started working correctly again - the only thing I did was switch to another branch to continue work, and open another copy of the project to test things as I thought of them. As soon as I ran the sample code it just blasted through all 10,000 iterations with no issue.

This doesn't explain what caused the issue and how to reproduce it but it makes me feel like there's some caching/buffering of requests somewhere that filled up possibly?

Comment: Can you describe the `Drivers` table. What are the execution time?

Comment: Table complexity doesn't appear to be a factor, the same behaviour occurs with a Settings table I have, which consists of an ID and 4 integers with no relationships or indexes. Execution time for these average out at ~2ms or so, even with the Drivers table which is a little more complex. SQL Profiler seems to indicate the SQL server is fine, it's firing through the queries quickly as they arrive, they just suddenly begin arriving slowly

Comment: The only thing that hit my eyes, is a mssing `await` on  `TestRepeatedQueries();` - but it is hardly the problem

Comment: Good spot, that `await` is actually there, I just missed it when writing out the question!

Comment: Does it reproduce in console app?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a different Entity/Table ?

Comment: I've not tried to reproduce in a console app yet, but this seems to happen regardless of the entity/table, no matter how simple/complex

Answer (score 0):

I'm belied it is related to the tracking entities.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking .
`await _context.SomeTable.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();` should helps.
I'm fall in that specific situation doing an complex import. The track entity structures grow too much. 
Other approach is limit the amount of operations by `DBContex` instances.

Comment: I thought this might be the case too, but the same behaviour appears to happen even with `AsNoTracking()` applied

Comment: Did you saw the generated queries?

Comment: Nothing unexpected, pretty much `SELECT TOP(1) s.[Id], s.[Col1], s.[Col2] FROM [SomeTable] AS [s]`. SQL server executes the query in <3ms so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the queries